# svn subversion Commit Failed Can't remove repoPath/db/transactions/nnn.n.txn/transactions

Tags: svn, commit, fsfs

I'm getting a strange error 
Can't remove 'repoPath/db/transactions/96479-3.txn/transactions'
 when I try to commit to the repository.  The commit actually does occur for both add and update of a file, but the client does not get updated to know the commit succeeded.  A further update on the client causes a conflict of its own file.

version 1.4.2 (r22196) running on linux.
using apache front end v 2.2.3

the repository is actually a copy of all the files from our production system.  Copied the files using rcp -rp sourceHost:/path ./localRepoOnQaBox

After copy, I used chown -R svn:svn on the repo path

```
fs_type is fsfs
```

Any idea why this behavior?

I should add that this setup works in our production environment, but after copying the repo to our test environment the error manifests.  Prod is hard hardware, QA is a vm.

Comment: try to add formatign to your code

Answer (score 1):

So, you do a commit, and the commit works. However, you get that error message and the working directory is left in a state of disarray?

There's a possibility of a post-commit hook is failing. Since the commit has already occurred, the repository is updated. However, since the post-processing of the commit never completes, your working directory isn't updated.

I suspect that someone is copying the changes to a server upon the commit, and they're doing this as a post-commit operation. This points to why you don't want to use post-commit hooks for this particular purpose, but that's another rant.

See if there's a post-commit hook that's failing. I bet once you deactivate the hook everything will work just fine. Replace the post-commit hook with either a crontab that runs every minute or use something like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) to do all of your post-commit hook needs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  There are no post-commit or other post- hooks enabled. Only pre-commit, pre-lock, pre-revprop-change and pre-unlock.  Is there anywhere else where post commit operations might be affected?